# Date conversion "Out of range value" error, converting dates under WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I'm working with a table that stores date values as integers under individual 'century', 'year', 'month', and 'day' columns. (The Year column only gets the last two digits of the year, and the Century column only ranges from 0 to 1 for years before 2000 and years after 2000 respectively.)

I'm trying to filter data after a specific date. Those columns must be converted to a single date or datetime value so it can be altered for report parameters. Right now the WHERE clause looks like this:

```
WHERE convert(datetime, CAST( ((19 + Table.Century) * 100 + Table.Year) as varchar) + '-' +  (Table.Month as varchar) + '-' + CAST(Table.Day as varchar), 121) > Convert(datetime,'2020-01-01', 121)
```

However, when I try to run the query, it always throws an error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

The issue seems to lie in the Month column. If I substitute any 30-day month (or February) into the Table.Month value, it will throw the error. 31-day months work fine. However, there are no out-of-bound dates in the data itself. Also, the statement runs fine and does not break if I put it in the SELECT statement.

I get the impression the WHERE statement is evaluating every possible Day value against every possible Month value for every possible Year value, etc. and ends up checking for dates like '2020-02-30'. How do I get it to stop that behavior?

Comment: Goodness!  I have not seen a century indicator since Y2K.

Answer (score 0):

Use `datefromparts()`:

```
where datefromparts(1900 + century * 100 + year, month, day) > '2020-01-01'
```

That said, you might have invalid values.  You should investigate those:

```
select century, year, month, day
from t
where try_convert(concat(1900 + century * 100 + year, '-'
                         month, '-', day)
                 ) is null
```

This works because SQL Server is good about interpreting dates such as `'2020-1-1'`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. DATEFROMPARTS is much more convenient. However, playing with it has led to the absurd discovery that the out-of-range error only happens when I attempt to compare my newly assembled date to another date. It displays all the dates just fine on its own in SELECT, but when I add a filter such as > 2020-01-01 suddenly the DATEFROMPARTS function says it's got invalid arguments.

Comment: @dhwu . . . Did you try the second query to find the bad dates?